# How to play *.mp4 in Silverlight (locally - no server)?

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, video, mp4

How to play *.mp4 in Silverlight (localy - no server)?
I have a file
How to play itr using xaml and c#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to do this is via a full-trust Silverlight 4 out-of-browser application - otherwise, Silverlight will not be able to access the file

Comment: It can access the file if the user selects it in an Open File dialog, no?